# Is it better to convert a planar pro-blem from 3d to 2d or just calculate it in 3d space?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have a a random oriented tetrahedron in 3d-space. I have to do calculations on each face, that are completely solvable in the face-plane.
My question is:
Should I transform (not project) the face so one spatial coordinate is constant (and I can drop it) or should I do all those operations just in 3d?

Please give an answer in aspect of computation speed.

Operations that will be performed are:
*area calculations
*discretization of the face
*intersections between lines and circles

edit:
clarifications:
Area calculations of circle segments / circle intersections and triangles.
How much area of a circle inside a triangle overlaps the triangle;
What is the intersection area between two circles that is inside a triangle

Discretization means, I put the triangle in a rectangle and fill it with N \approx 200 points. Then I find the points that are inside the triangle and use them for further calculations.

Comment: This description is insufficient. What do you mean by discretization ? What lines and circles ???

Comment: And also what area calculations? Do you just mean calculating the area of the faces? - if so just take 1/2 of the magnitude of the side vectors' cross product

Comment: I've edited the OP. Hopefully it's enough to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd convert to 2D because:

1. 2D is easier to work with.
2. Area calculations in 2D don't even require a square root. `float triArea = abs(cross(b-a, c-a))`
3. If you'd be working in 3D, you'd have to transform to and from 2D for your discretization and intersection passes anyway (since you'd be dealing with 2D objects)
4. Calculations in 2D are significantly easier.

No matter what the problem is, it is always better to convert a 3D planar problem to 2D. Everything becomes much more easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you will only perform these operation a few times against a few objects, then performing the operations in 3D will be faster as you will have the overhead to convert the objects from 3D to 2D and convert the computed result from 2D back to 3D. However, if you need to perform these operations many many times, then these overhead will become relatively small compared to the time you will save by operating in 2D.